# Unable to post to built API - getting null values

Tags: c#, api

I've written an API which is callable by Postman, no problems.   However, when I try to call my API from within another C# project, the API receives NULL data.  Here is my API Controller (Postman calls this, no problem):

```
public class BuildVirtualMachineController : ApiController
    {        
        public HttpResponseMessage Post(VirtualMachine virtualMachine)
        {
            System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationContext vc = new ValidationContext(virtualMachine);
            ICollection<ValidationResult> results = new List<ValidationResult>();
            bool isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(virtualMachine, vc, results, true);

            if(!isValid)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
            }

            string theReturn = JenkinsREST.BuildVirtualMachine(virtualMachine);

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, theReturn); 
        }
```

You can see that it expects JSON which can be turned into a VirtualMachine objects.  Here is what Postman sends to it:

```
{
    "Hostname": "pocdua133",
    "IPAddress": "172.30.32.133",
    "ResourceGroup": "hud-edw-poc-rg",
    "StorageAccount": "sapocimages",
    "BaseImage": "Windows 2016"
}
```

This works without a problem.   Now here is my code within my application to call my API, which is when I get a null value even though the data are identical:

```
protected void BuildBtn_BuildVirtualMachine(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var wb = new WebClient())
            {

                string url = "http://localhost:54587/api/v1/BuildVirtualMachine";

                string queryString = @"{ ""Hostname:""" + Hostname.Text + @""",IPAddress:""" + IPAddress.Text + @""",ResourceGroup:""" + ResourceGroups.SelectedItem.Text + @""",StorageAccount:""" + StorageAccount.Text + @""",BaseImage:""" + BaseImage.Text + @"""}";

                string password = "73c986bcaae14a6a93d345c270f3e1ba";
                string username = "admin";

                string basicAuthToken = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
                wb.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + basicAuthToken;
                wb.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
                wb.Headers.Add("user", "admin:73c986bcaae14a6a93d345c270f3e1ba");

                string response = wb.UploadString(url, queryString);
                WebHeaderCollection results = wb.ResponseHeaders;
                //return results.ToString();

            }
        }
```

Here is my virtual machine model as defined in my API, if it helps:

```
public class VirtualMachine
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Hostname is required.")]
        public string Hostname { get; set; }        
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "IP address is either not given or in improper format")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3}$")]        
        public string IPAddress { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Resource group is required.")]
        public string ResourceGroup { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Storage account is required.")]
        public string StorageAccount { get; set; }    
        [Required]
        public string BaseImage { get; set; }
        [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue("Standard_DS2_v2")]
        public string VMSize { get; set; }
        [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue("apps")]
        string VHDContainer { get; set; }
    }
```

I've used similar code to call other APIs, and my JSON looks the same as it does in Postman, so why does the POST always give my API a null value whereas Postman does not?

Thanks!

Duane

Comment: Why are you sending query string and not a json object in the body of request ? It looks as you're confusing stringified json with regular json

Comment: I most likely am, what would a JSON object look like, how would I construct one?  I apologize for being such a noob at this.

Comment: @NicoRiff I'm not getting any return code, my API is running with a breakpoint so that I can see what comes in, and the incoming data is NULL.

Comment: @Fabjan how would I construct the actual JSON?  What does my application need to do to properly post to my API's method?

Comment: I got it, it seemed to be a combination of bad JSON and content type, I recreated my VirtualMachine model within my application, did the JsonConvert.SerializeObject approach, set content type to application/json, and then used wb.UpLoadString(new Uri(url), "POST", dataString); where dataString is the SerializedObject(vm) result (vm is my VirtualMachine object).

I hope this helps others.

Comment: Never mind, it worked once, then I'm getting "unsupported media type", 415 errors.

Comment: Why are you sending JSON in a querystring rather than POST body? Why are you manually building JSON through string concatentation?

Comment: I'm not anymore, I'm creating the object and then serializing it.